# app.config file in a C++/CLI project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, c++-cli, app-config

I am trying to make an executable work under VS Express 2012. Upon execution, I get the message "Mixed mode assembly is built against version ‘v2.0.50727′ of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information".

From numerous posts, I see that it suffices to insert a tag in the `app.config` file. I have added an `app.config` file to the project with appropriate content, to no avail. But I guess that my file is just not taken into account at compile-time, as no `<project>.exe.config` file is generated. [If I create one manually next to the `.exe`, that works.]

My question is not about how to achieve framework version compatibility, it is about how to let VS handle the `app.config` file during a build. (Of course I can add a post-build event, but I was expecting that to be a built-in mechanism.)

Comment: The C++ build system does not have that goody.  Keep what you have.

Comment: @HansPassant: you are right. You can enter this as an answer if you want.

Comment: This question is still valid. I'm trying to modify a native built project to add /cli and get managed code so that I can leverage the built in code metrics tools rather than rely on open source CCCC.

Comment: @RossYoungblood: possibly irrelevant, but can't you create a managed project and insert your sources into it ?

Comment: Unfortunately no.  The native headers we use define main() and use MFC.  This is part of a propriatary embedded system runtime we use.
Managed code would run slower which would cost our clients $$.
I would need to develop a "Managed" header library to insert the sources into.